# Cannot access django-rosetta since I added a new app to project

Tags: python, django, django-rosetta

I have been using **django-rosetta** for a while in my project, but when I added a new app `ExcursionsManagerApp`, I get this error when I try to access **rosetta's** admin page:

```
AttributeError at /es/rosetta/files/project/
module 'ExcursionsManagerApp' has no attribute '__file__'
```

I don't know what causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was that my app directory was missing the `__init__.py` file. I added it, and everything started to work again.